# How to config the Odoo base URL

Tags: odoo

Is there any method to config the `Odoo` base URL from

```
https://SOME_URL/web...
```

to

```
https://SOME_URL/PROJECT_NAME/web...?
```

Can it be done through `Odoo.conf` itself or something else?
I tried to search and questions about it through the community but still had no luck at all.

Answer (score 0):

To get that working I think you will need to configure a reverse proxy to serve that URL `https://SOME_URL/PROJECT_NAME` against your Odoo instance and after that maybe that works completely if you set the value of the System Parameters `web.base.url` to that `https://SOME_URL/PROJECT_NAME` and also `web.base.url.freeze` to any value like `True` to avoid Odoo change the value of `web.base.url` after the admin login. Those values need to be set on the Odoo records accesible from the Menu `Settings / Technical / Parameters / System Parameters`